# With package lstlistings the word “columns” appears before every code

Tags: listings, keywords

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstlistings}
\lstset {language=C++,
    basicstyle=\small
    columns=flexible,
    stepnumber=0.8,
    numbersep=8pt,
    tabsize=4,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
CODE
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the when I create the PDF I get

somewhat like

PDF Starts:

columns

CODE

:PDF Ends

Why is there a "columns" before my CODE and how can I remove it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is a bunch of errors: `\usepackage{listings}`, not `lstlistings` and there is `,` missing after `\small` (which causes your problem), but another error is `\end{listing}` .. it should read `\end{lstlisting}`

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) see if you are not missing a comma after `\small`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma missing after `\small` makes the pdfcompiler write *columns* in your pdf. In the following code the script is correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset {language=C++,
    basicstyle=\small,
    columns=flexible,
    stepnumber=0.8,
    numbersep=8pt,
    tabsize=4,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
CODE
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```